# Angular: how to convert time from 00:00:01 to 8 min 49 second format?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datefilter, date-pipe

I want to convert time from 00:00:01 (which is not a date object) to 8 min 49 second format.

I went through Angular 'date pipe' documentation also but I didn't get any solution.

Comment: any feedback on the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular date pipes is the way to go... This should work for you in your **HTML**:

**Update**:
from your comments, i gather that you have a time string, due to which you'd first have to convert that time string into a date... after that, the Angular Date pipe will handle the rest;

relevant **TS**:

```
  priyankaTime = '08:04:01';
  priyankaDate;
  constructor() {

    this.priyankaFunction()
  }

  priyankaFunction() {
    var origStr = this.priyankaTime;
    var n = origStr.search(":");
    var hrPart = origStr.substring(0, n);

    var str = origStr.substring(n + 1, origStr.length);
    var n = str.search(":");
    var minPart = str.substring(0, 2);

    var str = str.substring(n + 1, str.length);
    var n = str.search(":");
    var secPart = str.substring(0, 2);
    console.log(hrPart, ':', minPart, ':', secPart);

    this.priyankaDate = new Date();
    this.priyankaDate.setHours(hrPart, minPart, secPart);

  }
```

relevant **HTML**:

```
{{myDateVariable | date:"h 'hours' mm 'minutes' ss 'seconds'" }}
```

check updated [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jh22gv?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But I'm not getting full date from backend .... I'm getting my execution date as 00:00:01 .. so when I'm trying apply filter its throwing error 'Unable to convert "00:00:01" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Comment: can you convert the date you get from the backend into a Date object?... by trying this: `this.myDateVariable = new Date(yourExecutionDateFromBackend)`

Comment: this means that `00:00:01` is not a valid date object; it is probably a string & you can't get a date from a string

Comment: its basically total duration .. starttime-endtime

Comment: are startTime and endTime Date object?... you can check by doing `let someVar = new Date(startTime )` and `let someVar = new Date(endTime )`...

Comment: @Priyanka, i have updated the answer against your particular case... now a time string (not a date object) will be parsed and converted into a date